# libnl: segfault when setting interface IPv6 address

Tags: c, networking, ipv6, netlink

I'm trying to set the IPv6 address of an interface, using `libnl`.
Going through the documentation and other resources, this is basically what I'm trying to do:

```c
static int set_ipv6(const char *if_name, const char *ipv6) {

    struct rtnl_link *link = NULL;
    struct nl_sock *sk = NULL;
    struct rtnl_addr *ipv6_addr = NULL;
    struct nl_addr* lo_ipv6_addr = NULL;
    struct nl_cache *link_cache = NULL;

    int err = 0;
    int ifindex = 0;

    sk = nl_socket_alloc();
    if ((err = nl_connect(sk, NETLINK_ROUTE)) < 0) {
        nl_perror(err, "nl_connect");
        return err;
    }

    ipv6_addr = rtnl_addr_alloc();
    if ((err = nl_addr_parse(ipv6, AF_INET6, &lo_ipv6_addr)) < 0) {
        nl_perror(err, "nl_addr_parse");
        return err;
    }

    printf("This part segfaults\n");
    if((err = rtnl_addr_set_local(ipv6_addr, lo_ipv6_addr)) < 0) {
        nl_perror(err, "rtnl_addr_set_local");
        return err;
    }

    if ((err = rtnl_link_alloc_cache(sk, AF_UNSPEC, &link_cache)) < 0) {
        nl_perror(err, "rtnl_link_alloc_cache");
        return err;
    }

    if((link = rtnl_link_get_by_name(link_cache, if_name)) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    if((ifindex = rtnl_link_get_ifindex(link)) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"index of %s not set\n", if_name);
        return -1;
    }

    rtnl_addr_set_ifindex(ipv6_addr, ifindex);

    rtnl_addr_set_link(ipv6_addr, link);

    if ((err = rtnl_addr_add(sk, ipv6_addr, 0)) < 0) {
        nl_perror(err, "rtnl_addr_add");
        return err;
    }

    nl_addr_put(lo_ipv6_addr);

    rtnl_addr_put(ipv6_addr);

    nl_cache_free(link_cache);

    nl_socket_free(sk);

    rtnl_link_put(link);

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, I call this code with something like:

```c
set_ipv6("veth1", "fc00:dead:cafe:1::2");
```

Where veth1 is a valid veth device.
However, for some odd reason, this code seems to segfault as soon as `rtnl_addr_set_local` is called, as it attempts to dereference an invalid address in the `rdi` register, when setting up the stack.

Any ideas what might be wrong or could this possibly be a bug in `libnl`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, it seems I was missing an include directive, more specifically - the addr.h header.

```
#include <netlink/route/addr.h>
```